# PHP sort ( rotate ) array based on value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, rotation

I have an array like this

```
<?php

$arr = Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [email] => peter@domain.com
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [email] => joe@domain.com
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [email] => bill@domain.com
            )
        );
```

I want to find email in array ... if email not exist dont chage anything but if email exist ... rotate array to right ...
when email placed last index ... use new array ... i dont know how i can solve this issue ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/how-to-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: @Rahuljuneja-DevOps i need to rotate array to left or right ... it's not simple sort

Comment: what do you mean by rotate an array

Comment: Include sample data like let's say searching for email `joe@domain.com` what should be output.

Comment: @Rahuljuneja-DevOps is the answer right ???

Answer (score 0):

It seems everything work fine ...
Is it right ???

```
$arr = Array(
Array('email' => "0@domain.com"),
Array('email' => "1@domain.com"),
Array('email' => "2@domain.com"),
);

while($arr[sizeof($arr)-1]['email'] != "1@domain.com" )
{
    array_push($arr, array_shift($arr));
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "<pre>";
```